# Drupal - Get custom taxonomy fields

Tags: arrays, drupal-8, drupal-taxonomy

I am trying to get a custom field assigned to taxonomy. I have tried this:

```
$vid = 'zeme';
$terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid);
```

$terms is now storing all the terms from the vocabulary called 'zeme'. The problem is when I print this variable, it doesnt show the custom field that I need to get.
Any idea how can I get this custom field?
My code looks like this:

```
 $vid = 'zeme';
  $terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid); 
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_data[] = array(
      'id' => $term->tid,
      'name' => $term->name
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the `loadTree function` official documentation :
[TermStorage::loadTree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermStorage.php/function/TermStorage%3A%3AloadTree/8.2.x)

When you use the `loadTree` function, it will only get you the minimal datas to save execution time. You can see there is a `$load_entities` parameter set to `false` by default.

> **bool $load_entities**: If TRUE, a full entity load will occur on the
>   term objects. Otherwise they are partial objects queried directly from
>   the {taxonomy_term_data} table to save execution time and memory
>   consumption when listing large numbers of terms. Defaults to FALSE.

So if you want to get all the datas of each of your taxonomy terms, you have to set `$load_entities` to `true`.

```php
$vid = 'zeme';
$terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadTree($vid, 0, null, true);
```

Comment: a lot of data, but the only usefull response, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this way from this post [Get custom fields assigned to taxonomy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232180/get-custom-fields-assigned-to-taxonomy/232256#232256):

```
$contact_countries = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadTree('contact_country');

$terms = array();

foreach($contact_countries as $contact_countrie) {
    $terms[] = array(
        'contact_country' => $contact_countrie->name,
        'contact_phone' => \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($contact_countrie->tid)->get('field_phone')->getValue()[0]['value'],
        'contact_flag' => \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($contact_countrie->tid)->get('field_category_flag')->entity->uri->value,
    );
}
```

Very usefull!

Answer (score 0):

public function getTaxonomyBuild(){
$terms = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadTree('faq_sec');

```
foreach($terms as $term) {
  $term_data[] = array(
    'name' => $term->name,
    'img' => file_create_url(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($term->tid)->get('field_sec_img')->entity->uri->value),
  );
}
    return $term_data;  
}
```

good solution